# Should we amend the help center text to allow "how to accomplish X" types of questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic, help-center

We get numerous questions on the form "how do I make X happen?", and these seem to be generally appreciated by the community. However, by a strict reading of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there is nothing to indicate that such questions are on topic on the site.

Should we amend the help center article to indicate that such questions are on topic?

Comment: I get the feeling that my question is the one that might have sparked this question. Just a feeling

Comment: @grimmsdottir Actually, this wasn't prompted by any one particular question at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, by adding the following bullet point under "questions are welcome that are about":

> - How to achieve a specified effect in a defined world, including by the use of technology or magic, while maintaning in-universe consistency